# Xpath Xquery : unable to add <DOCTYPE!> in xml while it is present in source xml file

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am modifying some nodes of existing configuration XML file.It contains `<!DOCTYPE>` line.

After changing XML file by using Xquery expression,resulting XML file contains all data as original except  `<!DOCTYPE>` line.

So,i want `<!DOCTYPE>` line in resulting XML file also.

My Source XML file : with `<!DOCTYPE>` line

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="c3p0.autoCommitOnClose">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
```

My Resulting XML file : has no `<!DOCTYPE>` line but i want it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="c3p0.autoCommitOnClose">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
```

my logical code for reading writing is:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

        DocumentBuilder builder;
        Document doc = null;
        XPathExpression expr = null;
        Node attributeElement = null;
        try {

            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            // creating input stream
            doc = builder.parse(file);
            XPathFactory xpf = XPathFactory.newInstance();
            XPath xpath = xpf.newXPath();

            //expr = xpath.compile("/sitemesh/mapping/@decorator");
            expr = xpath.compile("/hibernate-configuration/session-factory/property/@name='connection.url'");
            attributeElement = (Node) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
            System.out.println("value:"+attributeElement.getNodeValue());

            //attributeElement.setNodeValue("/WEB-INF/views/decorators/" + themeName);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("e:"+e);
        }


        // writing xml file
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory
                .newInstance();
        Transformer transformer;
        try {
            transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(file);// creating output
                                                            // stream
            transformer.transform(source, result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
```

Simply after changing some node of XML file,resulting file does not contain any `<!DOCTYPE>`  line

Please help ,how to add `<!doctype>` line in my resulting xml.Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got The answer.
While writing file after edit...

```
transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_SYSTEM,
                            "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd");
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(file);// creating output
                                                            // stream
            transformer.transform(source, result);
```

**Just setOutPutProperty....**  to anything you want

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hardcoding the DOCTYPE statement, use a string varible. It will help us to maintain loose coupling in code.

```
String doctype="http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd";
transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_SYSTEM,doctype);
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(file);// creating output stream                                                    
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

If you want many such doctypes you can maintain it in a properties file also. So that it will be easy to change if necessary in future.